# Sizing Inline SVGs

Tags: css, svg

I am using a couple of icons from https://leungwensen.github.io/svg-icon–which is a great resource–in a web app.

I can display and style them utilizing the `use` statement where I put the "sprite-sheet" in the top of the file:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" style="width:0;height:0;position:absolute;overflow:hidden;">
    <defs>
        <symbol viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" aria-labelledby="bisi-ant-check-circle-o-title" id="si-ant-check-circle-o"><title id="bisi-ant-check-circle-o-title">icon check-circle-o</title><path d="M821 331q-9-9-22.5-9t-22.5 9L383 713 247 584q-9-10-22.5-10T202 584q-10 9-10 22.5t10 22.5l158 152q10 9 23 9t23-9l415-405q10-9 10-22.5T821 331zM512 64q91 0 174 36 80 33 142 96 63 62 96 142 36 83 36 174t-36 174q-33 80-96 142-62 63-142 96-83 36-174 36t-174-36q-80-33-143-96-61-61-95-142-36-83-36-174t36-174q33-80 96-142 62-63 142-96 83-36 174-36zm0-64Q408 0 313 41T150 150 41 313 0 512t41 199 109 163 163 109 199 41 199-41 163-109 109-163 41-199-41-199-109-163T711 41 512 0z"/></symbol>
        <symbol viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" aria-labelledby="dnsi-ant-frown-title" id="si-ant-frown"><title id="dnsi-ant-frown-title">icon frown</title><path d="M512 64q91 0 174 35 81 34 143 96t96 143q35 83 35 174t-35 174q-34 81-96 143t-143 96q-83 35-174 35t-174-35q-81-34-143-96T99 686q-35-83-35-174t35-174q34-81 96-143t143-96q83-35 174-35zm0-64Q373 0 255 68.5T68.5 255 0 512t68.5 257T255 955.5t257 68.5 257-68.5T955.5 769t68.5-257-68.5-257T769 68.5 512 0zM224 446q-13 0-22.5-9.5T192 414v-64q0-13 9.5-22.5T224 318t22.5 9.5T256 350v64q0 13-9.5 22.5T224 446zm575 0q-13 0-22.5-9.5T767 414v-64q0-13 9.5-22.5T799 318t22.5 9.5T831 350v64q0 13-9.5 22.5T799 446zM192 577zm640 0zm-320-65q-106 0-182 74-61 60-73 144-2 14 7.5 25t23.5 11q12 0 21-8t11-19q9-62 55-107 57-56 137-56t137 56q46 45 55 107 2 12 11 19.5t21 7.5q14 0 24-11t7-25q-12-83-73-144-76-74-182-74z"/></symbol>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

And then later reference the IDs:

```
<svg><use xlink:href="#si-ant-frown"></use></svg>
```

But when I try to just include the individual SVGs inline, I can't seem to get the sizing right. Seems like there's supposed to be a balance between the `viewbox` and the `width` and `height` properties, but I'm either seeing a portion of a giant image or a smaller image with a huge empty field around it.

## huge empty field:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 5000 5000" version="1.1" style="width:200;height:200;position:absolute;">
    <path d="M512 0Q408 0 313 41T150 150 41 313 0 512t41 199 109 163 163 109 199 41 199-41 163-109 109-163 41-199-41-199-109-163T711 41 512 0zm309 376L406 781q-10 9-23 9t-23-9L202 629q-10-9-10-22.5t10-22.5q9-10 22.5-10t22.5 10l136 129 393-382q9-9 22.5-9t22.5 9q10 9 10 22.5T821 376z"/>
</svg>
```

## partial giant image:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 200 200" version="1.1" style="width:500;height:500;position:absolute;">
    <path d="M512 0Q408 0 313 41T150 150 41 313 0 512t41 199 109 163 163 109 199 41 199-41 163-109 109-163 41-199-41-199-109-163T711 41 512 0zm309 376L406 781q-10 9-23 9t-23-9L202 629q-10-9-10-22.5t10-22.5q9-10 22.5-10t22.5 10l136 129 393-382q9-9 22.5-9t22.5 9q10 9 10 22.5T821 376z"/>
</svg>
```

Does someone feel like explaining the relationship between the `path`s, `viewbox` and `height`/`width` or should I just delete this question and study [Sara Soueidan](https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems)?

In gratitude as always.

Comment: The `<symbol>` comes with a suitable `viewBox`. Why are you experimenting with other values?

Comment: Because I'm interested in how to achieve this without using the `use` approach. Just inline svg. Is that not clear in the question?

Comment: My point was that the `viewBox` attribute in the `<symbol>` should be correct. Just copy it across to your inline SVG.  Ie. `<svg viewBox="0 0 1024 1024"...`